# QGIS Map Tip can't display photos on the network computer

Tags: qgis, maptips

I'm using **Map Tip** to display image but if photo store in my computer it display ok ,example:

`img src="C:\test.jpg"`

But if photo store on a computer in my local network it can't display ,example:

`img src = " \\computer1\Folder1\photo.jpg "`

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Probably you need to start with `file:///SERVER_NAME:` before \computer1. Can you start your file explorer and (1) highlight the file (2) hold [SHIFT] key (3) right-click the mouse (4) copy as path (5) paste on a text editor ?

Comment: Fabulous, thanks. Allow me to summarize it as an answer. (please edit as you see necessary).

Answer (score 4):

To display an image on MapTip in a network environment, we can refer the link to the source in a `file:///SERVER_NAME:` style.

If you are in Windows network and need to find the path to the file, please follow:

1. Open file explorer
2. highlight the file and hold [SHIFT] key
3. right-click the mouse button
4. `copy as path`
5. paste on a text editor